# JS/HTML: Merge selected multiple <td> from a column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help to solve my problem based on the title above. Currently, I want to create an event calendar. From the given picture below, I want to merge the selected  on the spot to become one  and can input the text on it. For more clear, you can see from this demo: https://javascript.daypilot.org/demo/lite/calendar/index.html

That's what I want.

[image]

Can anyone know the codes? teach me, please.

Comment: Use `rowspan` or `col-*` if you are using bootstrap table

Comment: already update my question

Comment: So you want something on top of the table? That's what on the example link you have given though

Comment: no need something on top of the table. Just after merge can enter text on td. no need to popup dialog.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can refer this page https://javascript.daypilot.org/calendar/    for code